# ¿Cuál es el nombre y la función de este operador : en Java?

Tags: java

¿Cuál es el nombre  y la función de este operador : en Java?

Fragmento de código :

```
for(double nota : notas)
{
    suma = suma + nota;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: En este caso no es un operador en sí mismo, es parte de la sintaxis del bucle for ampliado

Comment: Ahí `:` **no es un *operador***, es solamente parte de la sintaxis acordada por los creadores de Java ([ver especificación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)). Ahí los dos puntos separan solamente las dos partes del encabezado del `for`, dichas partes son: la variable (a la izquierda)  y la expresión (a la derecha). Lo que hace y significa cada parte viene bien explicado también en la especificación del lenguaje. `:` se usa en otros casos, como en los *operadores ternarios*, para indicar la frontera entre el resultado verdadero y el falso.

Comment: Como nota al margen, estas cosas en los lenguajes se llama sugar syntax, y representan formas mas rapidas de escribir el mismo codigo.

Comment: En la pregunta que formulé dije operador a " : " basado en el Operador condicional " ?: ".

Answer (score 4):

Lo cierto es que se puede usar de varias formas. Una de ellas, la de tu ejemplo, es para lo que llaman *for-each*. Pero los dos puntos tienen más usos en general en Java.

1. For-each:

```
String[] ss = { "Hola", "mundo" };
for (String s: ss) {
    System.out.print(s); // Muestra primero "Hola" y "mundo" en la segunda iteración del bucle.
```

2. Condición ternaria:

```
int num1 = (num2 < 5) ? 1 : -1; // Si num2 es menor que 5, num1 valdrá 1, en otro caso valdrá -1.
```

3. `continue` o `break` con etiquetas:

```
etiqueta: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        if (i < 5) {
            break etiqueta; // Sale del bucle exterior, un break normal saldría del interior.
        }
    }
}
```

4. Aserciones:

```
int a = factorial(b);
assert a >= 0: "Un factorial no puede ser menor a 0"; // Si la condición es falsa, se lanza un AssertionError con el mensaje.
```

5. switch-case:

```
switch (tipo) {
    case ESPACIO:
    case INTRO:
        break;
    case NUMERO:
        System.out.print("Numero: " + valor);
    default:
        System.out.print("Valor inesperado" + valor);
}
```

6. También existe otro operador que usa los dos puntos, para hacer referencias a métodos, es el doble dos puntos. Esto es otra cosa, pero lo dejo aquí porque usa los dos puntos:

```
class Persona {
    public static int compararPorEdad(Persona a, Persona b) {
        return a.cumple.compareTo(b.cumple);
    }
}

Arrays.sort(personas, Persona::compararPorEdad);
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399590/what-does-the-colon-operator-do

Comment: Pero en el caso 6 no son los dos puntos en sí, sino los dobles dos puntos `::` que tendrían otro significado ¿no? Ver por ejemplo [aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-double-colon-operator) y también [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20001427/5587982). Estaríamos entrando ya en otro terreno.

Comment: @A.Cedano toda la razón. He editado la respuesta dejándolo como un poco más separado, pero no lo he quitado.

Answer (score 2):

Se llama `forEach` sirve para recorrer `array` y listas en Java.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo para que veas su funcionamiento:

```
Persona p1 = new Persona("juan", "sanchez", 20)
Persona p2 = new Persona("ana", "gomez", 12);
Persona p3 = new Persona("pedro", "gutierrez", 40);
List<Persona> lista = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3);

//Recorremos la lista anterior con un forEach:
for (Persona p : lista) {
      System.out.println(p.getNombre());
      System.out.println(p.getApellidos());
      System.out.println(p.getEdad());   
}
```

Y obtenemos por consola lo siguiente:

```
juan
sanchez
20
ana
gomez
12
pedro
gutierrez
40
```

Comment: Realmente el nombre en inglés es *enhanced for*, quizá podríamos traducirlo como *bucle for aumentado*.

Comment: @PabloLozano pero creo que su duda no es con respecto al `for`, el pregunta por ***el operador `:`***, por lo que creo que su duda es sobre los dos puntos. Sólo que los dos puntos no son un *operador*, realmente ellos no operan nada. Por llamarle de alguna manera, en la sintaxis de Java los dos puntos serían algo así como un ***delimitador*** (indican que antes de ellos va una cosa y después de ellos va otra cosa).

Comment: Sí, pero puesto que en este caso forma parte de la sintaxis, creo que es correcto asumir que no conoce este bucle

Comment: algunos lo conoceos como "for mejorado"